# Good freeware for solving equations symbolically

Tags: math-software

Many years ago I used maple to solve equations symbolically. Are there any good freeware alternatives?

I have three equations in three unknowns and want to find the solution symbolically

Comment: Sage is free, open source, and will do this. http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: Perhaps you could post your equations? Their nature might be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at Sage, Maxima and others for specialized fields.

See [*Comparison of CAS programs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).

There is even a Mathematica like one called Mathics.

For example, if you are looking for [*Geometry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_geometry_software), there are choices too.

By the way, for your problem, you could just try [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Regards

Comment: Nice suggestions, Amzoti! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you! You are a very helpful poster on here and I enjoy your answers! Regards

Comment: You're welcome, Amzoti! And thank you! You are very helpful too, in comments and in answers!

Answer (score 2):

There is a Java-based open-source program called Symbolic Equation Manipulator (formerly MathDrag'n) http://equation.sourceforge.net/ that allows you to enter a formula and then drag the variables around to manipulate, re-arrange, and refactor it. It allows you to do variable substitutions between formulas. It tracks the history of your work. It's not currently maintained, but it works. I've had a very hard time finding any other free program or app that does this!